# Qt: Display byte from QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt4, qbytearray

This might be a stupid question but I can't seem to find how to display a byte from a QByteArray as "01011000" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the function is not related to the scope of `QByteArray`, which is a simple byte container. Instead, you need to get the specific byte (as `char`) to print and show singles bits from it. For instance, try this (magic):

```
char myByte = myByteArray.at(0);

for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) {
    std::cout << ((myByte >> i) & 1);
}
```

Assuming that your machine has 8-bit bytes (which is not as a bold statement as it would have been 20 years ago).

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I still find it stupid that there isn't a build in method for that.